# PostgreSQL Copy to FTP Server

Tags: postgresql, ftp

we can use

```
copy (select * from mytbl) to 'D:/products.csv' with csv header
```

to import `data` in `mytbl` to `local disk D`

so is it possible to use the same method to upload the file directly into a `FTP-Server` ?

i tried like this

```
copy (select * from mytbl) to 'ftp://usrname:mypasswrd@ftp.drivehq.com/masters/3/product/products.csv' with csv header
```

but got this `error`

```
ERROR: relative path not allowed for COPY to file
SQL state: 42602
```

using `PostgreSQL 9.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not support any source/destination for `COPY` other than a file or `stdin`/`stdout`.

What you *can* do is `COPY` to `stdout` and pipe that to a program that writes the data to the ftp dir. `psql`'s `\copy` is useful for this:

```
psql -c "\copy mytable to stdout with (format csv, header)" | ncftpput -c my.ftp.host /path/on/host
```

You can use any tool that accepts the input data on a pipe to write to the remote ftp file; `ncftpput` is just one option.

A future PostgreSQL version may add support for invoking `COPY` with a pipe, e.g. `COPY ... TO '|/some/command'`, but there are serious security concerns with running programs under the PostgreSQL user that would make this a superuser-only operation and of questionable safety even then. It's much safer to run the program client-side, and `psql` is ideal for that.